# How to install Go without root

Tags: go, installation, root

I am trying install Go in my server but I don't have root permission to create files and directories in root folder.
Firstly, I am extracting it into `/home/vt_admin/local/go`.

Then, I set up environment

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/vt_admin/local/go/bin
$ export GOPATH=$GOPATH:/home/vt_admin/go
$ export GOROOT=$GOROOT:/home/vt_admin/local/go
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

But when I run `go version`, the result is `-bash: /home/vt_admin/local/go/bin/go: permission denied`.
So, How can I do fix this?

Comment: the exports (first 3 lines) are in your `~/.bash_profile` file, right? And `source ~/.bash_profile` you do in terminal before running `go version`?

Comment: Your path need to be in the  `bin` directory change it to `export PATH=$PATH:/home/vt_admin/local/go/bin`

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava I implemented but have other error ```-bash: /home/vt_admin/local/go/bin/go: Permission denied```

Comment: @Abhijit-K Yeb :D

Answer (score 2):

As per [Go official install instructions](https://golang.org/doc/install) (select Linux)
`go` tool binary is in `bin/` subdirectory relative to the tarball root. Follow step 2 of install instructions to get `go` executable in `PATH`:

(replace `/usr/local/go/bin` with `/home/vt_admin/local/go/bin` in below)

> Add `/usr/local/go/bin` to the `PATH` environment variable.
> You can do this by adding the following line to your `$HOME/.profile` or `/etc/profile` (for a system-wide installation):
>
> `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`
> Note: Changes made to a profile file may not apply until the next time you log into your > computer. To apply the changes immediately, just run the shell commands directly or execute them from the profile using a command such as source `$HOME/.profile`.

Other than that your setup is ok.

Comment: I implemented like your way but still have error ```-bash: /home/vt_admin/local/go/bin/go: Permission denied```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I can't implement the first instruction because I dont have the root access

Comment: You need replace `/usr/local/go/bin` with your `/home/vt_admin/local/go/bin`. I will update my answer to make it more clear. If you still getting permission denied error it might also mean that you downloaded `go` package for wrong architecture (and hence not executable) or because there's security policy installed that prevents running binaries outside system directories (pretty common for e.g. web hostings).

Comment: I think the first situation maybe wrong cause I have installed on the other server successful (I have root permission) by this package. In the second situation, how to know find out information that Golang  prevents running binaries outside system directories?

Comment: Because I have find out on Internet but dont see in4mation

Comment: It's not golang, it's operating system administrator. If you know there's no such restriction just fixing PATH to point to /home/vt_admin/local/go/bin should be all you need.

Comment: When I run ```which go```. The rusult is ```/usr/bin/which: no go in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/vt_admin/.local/bin:/home/vt_admin/bin:/home/vt_admin/go/bin:/home/vt_admin/go/bin)``` . About operating system admin, I think it's not reason cause I am using server test. It's just don't have Internet :D

Comment: Tks u. The reason is operating system admin cause I have tried on my PC, It's running :(